# ASP.Net MVC : How to do extract and automatic data mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

suppose i have link like **www.mysite.com/Certificate/data/C001-P2003**

my controller name is Certificate and action name data

```
public class CertificateController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Data(string certid,string studid)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

i want to know what i need to develop which will extract id and break into two part separated by hyphen and map two data to Data action.

C001 will map to certid and P2003 will map to studid. so i need concept how to do it?

do i need to develop any action filter ?

do i need to write any custom value provider ?

do i need to write any custom model binder ?

i do not want to break the data inside action rather i want to do it out of action. so suggest me something best idea. thanks

Comment: why negative mark instead of sharing concept to achieve it with best idea?

Comment: You can't change url to split this values? If it always will be split by dash I will use one parameter in action and split it inside action.

Comment: @Sousuke i do not want to change url but i believe there should be some way to split the route value before request reaching to action method. after split we can bind value to action parameters.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so people can use it to reproduce the problem and give much better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a convention in your `RouteConfig` that will map the route you want.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CertificateData",
    url: "Certificate/data/{certid}-{studid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Certificate", action = "Data"}
);
```

Or enable Attribute Routing and use template on action to match the desired url

```
// GET Certificate/data/C001-P2003
[Route("Certificate/data/{certid}-{studid}")]
public ActionResult Data(string certid,string studid) {...}
```